# WebRTC Streaming not working for broadcasting Gstreamer webrtcbin

Tags: python, webrtc, gstreamer

We have setup gstreamer streaming pipeline that streams live video with webrtcbin.

We are able to see the stream successfully. Problem occurs when we try to add a new webrtcbin to same pipeline with tee. We are able to attach and send sdp and ice messages to the receiver browser. But there is no stream.

Only difference that I have seen is that the second sdp offer generated has transreciver set to index 1, and as we keep adding more streams the transreciver value keeps increasing.

Does receiver side has to do something to handle the changing tranreciver. Or we are sending incorrect sdp.

GStreamer Pipeline:

src => queue ! video/x-h264,profile=high ! rtph264pay ! application/x-rtp,media=video,encoding-name=H264,payload=123 ! tee ! queue ! webrtcbin bundle-policy=max-bundle stun-server=stun:stun.l.google.com:19302
We add new webrtcbin to tee by creating queue ! webrtcbin and attaching queue to tee.